# How to make this matching algorithm run faster?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, performance-testing, matching

I have two lists of pointers to a data structure X, the algorithm is very simple:

It loops over the first list A and try to find the the first matching element in list B. The requirement is to have at least 50k elements in each list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct X {
    std::string field_1;
    std::string field_2;
    std::string field_3;
    std::string field_4;

    X(std::string f1, std::string f2, std::string f3, std::string f4)
        : field_1(f1)
        , field_2(f2)
        , field_3(f3)
        , field_4(f4)
    {};

    bool equal(const std::shared_ptr<X>& x) {
        return  (x->field_1 == field_1) &&
                (x->field_2 == field_2) &&
                (x->field_3 == field_3) &&
                (x->field_4 == field_4);
    };

    X *match = nullptr;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<X> X_ptr;


class Timer
{
public:
    Timer(std::string name) : beg_(clock_::now()), name_(name) {}

    ~Timer() {
        std::cout << "Elapsed(" << name_ << "): " << elapsed() << std::endl;
    }

    void reset() { beg_ = clock_::now(); }
    double elapsed() const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<second_>
            (clock_::now() - beg_).count();
    }

private:
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock_;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1> > second_;
    std::chrono::time_point<clock_> beg_;

    std::string name_;
};


std::string random_string(size_t length)
{
    auto randchar = []() -> char
    {
        const char charset[] =
            "0123456789"
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        const size_t max_index = (sizeof(charset) - 1);
        return charset[rand() % max_index];
    };
    std::string str(length, 0);
    std::generate_n(str.begin(), length, randchar);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    Timer t("main");

    std::vector <X_ptr> list_A;
    std::vector <X_ptr> list_B;

    const int MAX_ELEM = 50000;

    list_A.reserve(MAX_ELEM);
    list_B.reserve(MAX_ELEM);

    {
        Timer t("insert");

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEM; i++) {
            list_A.push_back(X_ptr(new X{ random_string(2), random_string(2), random_string(2), random_string(2) }));
            list_B.push_back(X_ptr(new X{ random_string(2), random_string(2), random_string(2), random_string(2) }));
        }
    }

    {
        Timer t("match");

        std::for_each(list_A.begin(), list_A.end(), [list_B](X_ptr& a) {
            auto found_b = std::find_if(list_B.begin(), list_B.end(), [a](const X_ptr& b) {
                return a->equal(b);
            });

            if (found_b != list_B.end()) {
                a->match = found_b->get();

                std::cout << "match OK \n";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

on my machine the program is running extremly slow:

```
Elapsed(insert): 0.05566
Elapsed(match): 98.3739
Elapsed(main): 98.452
```

Would appreciate it if you can think of any other way to optimize it to run faster.

Comment: Is the list order fixed or can you sort it before using?

Comment: `stable_sort` list_B before. Then you can use binary_search on list_b instead of find_if.

Comment: @MatthiasB, yes it can be sorted. but on which field?

Comment: would be more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How many lookup happen per program run?  How many inserts happen between lookups?

Comment: The biggest gains in scenarios such as this one are to be had by not having to walk the entire list for the search and one way of doing that is to structure it in such a way that it can be sorted and then use a binary search. Further gains can then be had by optimising the string comparisons, for example by generating a hash code when the string is assigned and just comparing hashes.

Comment: Micro-optimizations: Pass string to functions as const reference (or in C++11 if you are keeping a copy, such as the constructor, you can pass by value and use `std::move`). Make charset static. You pass `a` into lambda by value. Could it be passed by (const) reference?

Comment: @user327843 Depends on your data. One simple option is to just use a concatination of all strings.

Comment: capture `list_B` by reference into the `for_each` lambda. Also, use `find_first_of` as the algorithm

Answer (score 5):

You are using vectors so each lookup into list_B takes O(n), where n is the number of elements in B.  This means the total algorithm is O(m*n), if m is the number of elements in list_A.  Thus if m and n a similar in size, you have a O(n^2) algorithm.  That is too slow for any large n.  To fix this, convert list_B into a unordered_map, (you can do this as part of this algorithm as the conversion is O(n)) where an element in the map's key is an element from list B and the value anything, say 0.  You can then perform lookups into the map in O(1) time using find() on the map.  Thus your algorithm becomes O(n), way better that O(n^2).

For example

```
       std::unordered_map< X_ptr, int > value_map;
       Time r t("match");

        std::for_each(list_B.begin(), list_B.end(), [&](X_ptr& b) {
                value_map[b] = 0;
        });

       std::for_each(list_A.begin(), list_A.end(), [value_map](X_ptr& a) {
            auto found_b = value_map.find( a );

            if ( found_b != value_map.end() )
            {
                a->match = found_b->first.get();

                std::cout << "match OK \n";
            }
        });
    }
```

Your Version:

```
Elapsed(insert): 0.0758608
Elapsed(match): 182.899
Elapsed(main): 182.991
```

New Version:

```
Elapsed(insert): 0.0719907
Elapsed(match): 0.0388562
Elapsed(main): 0.130884
```

Comment: Using hash table keys as a lookup table is useful trick for the coding toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like the following:

```
std::sort(list_B.begin(), list_B.end(), deref_less<X>);
{
    Timer t("match");

    for (const auto& a : list_A) {
        auto it = std::lower_bound(list_B.begin(), list_B.end(), a, deref_less<X>);

        if (it != list_B.end() && **it == *a) {
            a->match = it->get();

            std::cout << "match OK \n";
        }
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/k669KK).